# Error in compiling Xv6 Kernal "Error: Couldn't find a riscv64 version of GCC/binutils."

Tags: environment-variables, homebrew, qemu, macos-monterey, xv6

I had followed all the steps mentioned here : https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2022/tools.html
but when I tried to "make qemu" I got following error.

```
% make qemu
***
*** Error: Couldn't find a riscv64 version of GCC/binutils.
*** To turn off this error, run 'gmake TOOLPREFIX= ...'.
***
gcc    -c -o kernel/entry.o kernel/entry.S
kernel/entry.S:5:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .text
              ^
kernel/entry.S:12:9: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'la'
        la sp, stack0
        ^~
kernel/entry.S:13:9: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'li'
        li a0, 1024*4
        ^~
kernel/entry.S:14:9: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'csrr'
        csrr a1, mhartid
        ^~~~
kernel/entry.S:15:9: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'addi'
        addi a1, a1, 1
        ^~~~
kernel/entry.S:16:9: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
        mul a0, a0, a1
        ^
kernel/entry.S:17:9: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
        add sp, sp, a0
        ^
kernel/entry.S:21:9: error: ambiguous instructions require an explicit suffix (could be 'jb', or 'jl')
        j spin
        ^
make: *** [kernel/entry.o] Error 1
%
```

I thought there may be some environment path error in including `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin` in ~/.bashrc file. My default shell is zsh and its ~/.zshrc file.
I added this line in ~/.zshrc file :

```
# for xv6kernel
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin
```

After adding it my new terminal's PATH variable had this output. So, I don't think its PATH issue.

```
% echo $PATH
... // Removed these paths for privacy
:/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain/bin
%
```

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052271/compile-xv6-on-mac#:%7E:text=brew%20install%20qemu%20x86_64%2Delf%2Dgcc%0A%0Aexport%20TOOLPREFIX%3Dx86_64%2Delf%2D%20%0Aexport%20QEMU%3Dqemu%2Dsystem%2Di386%0A%0Amake%20qemu) (commands below) did not work for me.

```
brew install qemu x86_64-elf-gcc

export TOOLPREFIX=x86_64-elf- 
export QEMU=qemu-system-i386

make qemu
```